# Persist nested entities (one-to-many) with a bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am creating a Spring Boot web application that is supposed to receive a JSON document via HTTP, parse it to the respective entity class, and persist the object. The JSON is a representation of a *Recipe* instance, and one recipe can have multiple *Step* objects associated with it.

***Recipe.java***

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Step> steps;

    // Additional attributes, constructors, getters and setters omitted
}
```

***Step.java***

```
@Entity
public class Step {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECIPE_ID")
    private Recipe recipe;

    // Additional attributes, constructors, getters and setters omitted
}
```

When sending the following JSON document to the application, however, the foreign key referencing `RECIPE_ID` within the step object is `null`, thus there is no connection between the recipe and its steps.

```
{
    "name": "Test recipe",
    "description": "Test description",
    "type": "Test",
    "cookingTime": 45,
    "preparationTime": 30,
    "thumbnail": "",
    "steps": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "name": "First step",
            "content": "Test content",
            "image": ""
        },
        {
            "number": 2,
            "name": "Second step",
            "content": "Test content",
            "image": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Should not the nested step objects also get persisted since `CascadeType.ALL` has been specified? Also, I am using a `RestController` to handle the request and a `JpaRepository` class for persistence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can  add @JsonBackReference annotation on @ManyToOne Side and @JsonManagedReference annotation on @OneToMany side.

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference("recipe_steps")
    private Set<Step> steps;

    // Additional attributes, constructors, getters and setters omitted
}


@Entity
public class Step {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECIPE_ID")
    @JsonBackReference("recipe_steps")
    private Recipe recipe;

    // Additional attributes, constructors, getters and setters omitted
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, no need for changing the controller logic.

Comment: Glad that it could help you :)

Comment: Annotations FTW

Answer (score 3):

In your controller, you will have to do something like this.

```
for (Step step : recipe.getSteps()) {
    step.setRecipe(recipe);
}
```

You are basically missing the back-reference in the `Step object` which is `null` when you post.